# Class FIle has no arguments at the constructor

Tags: java, file, constructor

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.io.File.separator;


public class File {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dirName = "Neis";
    File dir = new File(dirName);


     } 
} // end of class File
```

Error:

```
constructor File in class File cannot be applied to given types;
File dir = new File(dirName);
           ^
required no arguments
```

---

Why has the constructor of File no arguments? In my different program, it worked like that but on a different computer.

Comment: You named your class `File`. So it's not trying to use `java.io.File`. It's trying to use **your** `File` class.

Answer (score 5):

You named your class `File`. Thus, when you use `new File`, it refers to your own class and not to `java.io.File`. You can solve this by writing: `new java.io.File(dirName)` instead... but I would advise you to just rename your own class. Naming your own classes the same as common core library classes is very confusing.